Exposition in Bach's fugue repeats?

Analyzing Bachs first fugue in C major
I can't understand something.
I have colored all the subjects and answers in the picture and wrote their structure in the picture below but it seems that the exposition repeats with different order in voices  or is it just the beginning of the development?
And why in the second exposition( I suppose ) we have the subject in the dominant in successive three voices ? Shouldn't the answer of a subject be a fifth or fourth transposed?

Another Question - I see a lot that Bach uses dissonance passing tone that moves stepwise up or down
Is it kind of a suspension? If it is
Can I have it on the strong beat like the second example I wrote
Because  know Bach use mostly triad consonance on strong beats 

The "exposition" is by definition the first statement of the theme in all the voices, why do you think that it continues beyond b.6?

Because it's literally the same as the first part the is no developement is applied even the countersubjects seem to be the same and harmony is the same

There are probably some great analytical answers to these questions and also the theory about form almost never perfectly lines up with the forms of actual compositions. In other words, we are often taught about an “ideal” fugue and there may be zero actual fugues written by Bach that match the theoretical ideal.

I was wondering if this is an actual specified part and has a name like double exposition fuge or re exposition but i'm not sure if such a thing exist

The first four entries are the exposition. The purpose there is to clearly state the tonic key alternating with the dominant.
The next series of subject/answer statements can be called middle entries. Why are they all in the dominant? Because basic musical forms commonly moved from a major key statement to the key of the dominant. Sonatas, fugues, etc. will follow that design.
As for chord tone versus non-chord-tones in subjects, remember fugues is a linear and contrapuntal art. Vertical dissonances are not only fairly common, it often provides great color and energy to the music.
You can do Roman numeral chord root analysis on fugues, but often it's more in line with the contrapuntal nature of fugues to forego that and analyze subject/answer entries, key changes, sections like links, episodes, stretto, along with melodic development methods like inversion, augmentation, truncation, fragmentation, etc.
Harmonic analysis can focus on cadence placement and keys, vertical intervals - as you might do in species counterpoint, and relative motion. Also, sequential passages especially in episodic passages. To be sure, you often find roots by fifths harmony, but you might think of that as simply the result of food voice leading and beside the point of what truly concerns fugues.

I want to add a few points about your specific questions.

Because it's literally the same as the first part the is no developement is applied even the countersubjects seem to be the same and harmony is the same

Your missing one important idea: melody. As the subject and answer get placed in each voice there is melodic development. It's simple development, but what is being argued here, did Bach write a bad fugue? This particular fugue is certainly one of the didactic fugues in the WTC.
Regarding the countersubjects, keep in mind when invertible counterpoint is used part of the point is you can use the various inversions to move the melodic material in the various voices. That develops melody with the individual voices, but it is also economical use of material and provides unity.
The tenor repeats the answer. You can call that a redundant entry. But, notice that the harmony around the two differs. Exact repetition, repetition without variation, is a way to develop melody. Sure, it's simple, but it is development. But, while the tenor melody repeats without variation, the harmonizing counterpoint does provide variety.

I thought fuges usually have 3 section exposition and developement and recapitulation( of course episodes between them )

Yes, but don't mix this up with the specific formal structure of sonata allegro form. There is an adage the fugue is not a form, but a procedure. Sonata allegro form, the idealized description, is a formula of key changes and thematic changes. Exposition, development, recapitulation in fugue does not carry the same formal expectation. (There is something called the academic fugue, which may interest you, and proscribes a series of fugal procedures, sort of analogous to the academic sonata design, but that is a 19th century thing, Bach didn't do it.) In fugue, think of exposition, development, recapitulation more generically as beginning, middle, end, where the beginning and end are about the tonic key and the middle is about not-the-tonic keys. Don't expect more than that.

Another Question - I see a lot that Bach uses dissonance passing tone that moves stepwise up or down Is it kind of a suspension? If it is Can I have it on the strong beat like the second example I wrote Because know Bach use mostly triad consonance on strong beats

Yes, in the Bach example, we are looking at passing motion. You can label the 2-3 as you did to see how the dissonance resolves. But sometimes the vertical alignment of pitches in Bach's contrapuntal writing is surprisingly dissonant. It isn't always clear homophonic writing with non-chord tone dissonances... because it's contrapuntal writing.
However, notice in the Bach example, the two parts separately should be perfectly clearly heard as figuration of a G major chord. That is the important thing to recognize, vertical dissonances notwithstanding.
When there is a lot of vertical dissonance in a passage try looking at the parts in isolation and you usually will find they are clearly in some key and can be understood in a harmonic sense as figuration of some kind of tonic/dominant chords.
If you try to write your own passages, I would recommend being very, very careful to evaluation what is happening in the model you emulate. Notice in Bach, that we have dissonances resolving to imperfect consonances (thirds) and the passage  can be reduced to just two lines moving in thirds. Also, there are no linear dissonances.
In your example, your top line outlines a tritone. That can be problematic. Also, your dissonances resolve to perfect rather than imperfect consonances. In two part writing imperfect consonances are preferred. The top part tritone outline could work if the harmony sense was a dominant of some kind, but the lower part outlines C to A and implied A minor chord. Your idea uses a contrary motion, which is a nice way to differentiate yours from the Bach model. But, it might be better if the bottom part was descending A G F and on down to E for a V4/2 I6 sense. Intervallically, that would give us 6 2-3 5-6, either imperfect consonances on the beat or resolutions to imperfect consonances.
You can approach writing your own studies from models different way, just try to be careful about what exactly you emulate from the model. For example, you could use the 2-3 resolution as the point of departure. How can you link those together differently from Bach? What are the resulting two melodic parts? If there are problems, does transposing to another part of the key help? etc. etc.

So the middle entries are different from developement section ? I thought fuges usually have 3 section exposition and developement and recapitulation( of course episodes between them )  with my second question i was wondering where dissonance should be applied ( are all none chord tone dissonances either a passingg tone or neighbour tone ... ? ) and when dissonances are in conjuct motion following a consonance does that imply a suspention?

No. I think you need to do a thorough reading of a few texts about fugue. There are many to choose from. Wikipedia covers you first follow up question directly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue#Development

I would read textbooks on fugue, but then don't get too bogged down in terminology. Understand the terminology, but spend more time and attention on actual fugue analysis. Look at JS Bach for certain, but add some other composers like Pachelbel. What they did in their fugue writing IS what fugue is, at least one era of fugue writing.

If you're unclear about non-chord tones that will be covered in a good harmony textbook like Kostka/Payne's Harmony. There is some variation in NCT definitions from textbook to textbook but on the whole it's pretty standardized.

Review the textbook, analyze real fugues. I think the study you did of subject/answer entries was good. Finish that one and then do about 10 total and compare them. Get a foundation in what actually happens in fugues from actual examples. Go back to the textbooks first to find answers to your questions, then post here is something is still unclear.

Thank you very much i'll surely study the book and analyze more fuges . In my second question   i understood  that if there are dissonances it's better if i resolvd them into imperfect consonances and it's must make vertical harmony at some point as you  used v4/2 to I6

Because i see that bach usually breaks most of the conterpoint rules when it comes to Chord tone dissonances like leaping to a 7 or leaping a tritone - but none chord tone dissonances are mostly double neighbour tones or anticipation ..

I recommend getting away from the "composer X breaking the rules..." Sure, study treatises and textbooks for "rules", but keep it in perspective. Whatever Church music "rules" (which were old even in the 18th century) were "broken" by composers they did so for some other more important musical reason. If that weren't the case, composers would all be writing conservative motets.
